# Keeping the structure intact in contentEditable Div

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, rich-text-editor

I am trying to build a **Rich Text Editor** from scratch, Seems like a really big & complex task, I know, The editor should make use of `Range` & selection apis instead of `execCommand`, be extensible and support basic editing features like paragraph alignment and inline styling.

I've found the `SlateJs` library which also allows you to build rich text editor. However I am determined to do this from scratch, even though I don't know where to start.

**The problem is that when the user types into my editor the text goes directly into container element with `contentEditable` div. However when the user types into `SlateJs` editor, The text goes into a three nested spans which are contained inside a `paragraph` element , You can inspect this here https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext**

How can I implement this behavior ?

`preventDefault` doesn't work on input but works on `keydown`

```js
editor.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=> {
     e.preventDefault()
    // if the key is a printable character
    if(event.key.length == 1){
        // this always appends to the last of paragraph even if the cursor is somewhere else
        this.topLevelParagraph.innerHTML += event.key
    }
})
```

The caret position doesn't change, Text always goes at last.

- What's the best way to fix this issue.
- I would appreciate if you could recommend articles or resources that can help me build a library like slatejs, rich text editor

Comment: I don't understand, so you want to build from scratch a rich text editor. You want to use `contenteditable` and `execCommand` or not? Also what is your code supposed to do? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: We can use `contentEditable` but not `execCommand` , My code doesn't work, so I asked the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that to maintain structure, You need to do some things

1 - Initial structure, You must create initial elements, wrappers and formatting inline elements and decide which element should / will take input from the user

2 - A `keydown` event on the container with `contentEditable` attribute , Now you can `preventDefault` on the event and put the key into the exact element inside the container, You must filter out keys that are not `printable characters`, You can filter control characters using `ascii` codes but I recommend you use `unicode`
I used `e.key.length == 1` and some other filters

3 - Now your input has gone into the box, or maybe not because you `preventedDefault`, You must also track user selection range and adjust it after every key, so input is at the right position, for example on each key you must collapse the current `range` at `endPosition + 1`, so the caret remains right next to the current letter typed

4 - You must handle `copy` `paste`, You don't have to handle backspace key, However after every user action, You must make sure the structure remains intact

You could go a separate way and create your own data structure, You take all the events from the browser and have a structure in your code that user changes instead of the text field and re render the object that takes the input / has changed.